# How to pause frame rate to display a frame rate dependent variable

Tags: processing

Im trying to display my score in a 2d sidescrolling videogame im making in processing. The problem is that my Score is dependent on the Framecount and after the character dies I want to display the score enlarged across the screen. The way my program works is that after the collision occurs a counter is set to a specific Number (100), each loop that counter will decrease and once it hits a certain number the program will restart. My Idea was to display the score in the time between collision and the program restarting. My Problem is that the Score will keep increasing, since the program is still running. Any Ideas on how I could solve this? I tried pausing the draw loop but that doesn't work since the game wont resume again. Thanks a lot for your help.

Here is my Score class:

```
public class Score {
 private PFont font;
 private int x, y; 
 private PImage img;




  //constructor
  public Score ( int x, int y, PFont font) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.font = font;       
  }

  public void draw () {

    Scorevar = frameCount/20;
    textFont(font);
    fill (0);
    //textAlign(CENTER);
    textMode(MODEL);
    text("Score = "+ Scorevar, x, y);

  }
}
```

Here is the part of my main loop which involves the score

```
void draw() {
  background (255);


  chari.draw();
 //collision and collison image
  if ( collide_count == 0 ) {
  chari.draw();
  }
   else {

 image( collide, chari.x+130, chari.y+100 );
 collide_count--;



 }
 if ( collide_count > 5 && collide_count < 80) {

   score2.draw();

 }


 if ( collide_count == 5) {


 frameCount = 0;
   setup();
 }

  blockfield.draw();

  score1.draw();




}
```

Code for collision :

```
public void update(float cY, float cW) {
      for ( int i =frameCount/200; i >0; i--) {
     //for (int i =frameCount/400; i >0; i--) {
     //moves blocks right to left
      block[i].x -=(frameCount/200);
      //spawns block when they leave the screen
      if (block[i].x < -Blockpic.width) {
       block[i].setX( random(width, width*2));
       block[i].setY( random (height));
       //println(block[i].x + " " + block[i].y);
      }

      if (block[i].x < 130) {
         if(block[i].y > cY && block[i].y < (cY+cW)){
            //println(collide_count + " with");
            collide_count = 100;


          }
      }
     }
   }
```

Comment: So, what's wrong with using a flag `bool StillPlaying` for instance.  After a collision set `StillPlaying = false` and check each time the score is due to increase.

Answer (score 1):

Just save the score value into a separate variable. Then use that variable to set the score for the death screen.

Comment: Hi thanks, but how would i save the value without it changing constantly? Since the score is the frame count.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, you have a value called frameCount which increases every frame. At any point, you could say currentCount = frameCount and that currentCount would not increase while the frameCount continues to.

Comment: I tried it but the problem seems to be that my deathscreen lasts a bunch of frames so it will still be increasing.

Comment: Can you clarify for me which condition in your code checks for death?

Comment: The way my program works is that after the collision occurs a counter is set to a specific Number (100), each loop that counter will decrease and once it hits a certain number the program will restart. I mentioned this in the question. Edit: the collision is

Comment: I understand that. What I am suggesting is that when that collision occurs, you set a different value equal to the current frame count value, which you can use to display the score.

Comment: well so in my code under the collision i set currentCount = frameCount. When I print the currentCount it still increases during the death screen.

Comment: I saved it in the question above at the end. Its the last lines of code.

Comment: Thank you. Try this. Create a boolean value called finished. when the game starts, set it to false. Then change "if(block[i].y > cY && block[i].y < (cY+cW)){" to "if(block[i].y > cY && block[i].y < (cY+cW) && !finished){" Inside the if statement, set finished to true. This will ensure that this only runs once per game and the value you set to currentCount will not change until the game starts over. Remember to set finished to false every time the game starts over.

Comment: Hi Im sorry I tried it and it wouldnt work. I turned it to false in the setup and to true in the collision and added the !finished.

Comment: Hi sorry yesterday evening was a bit late for me I retried by seeting the value in the collsion and tieing the score output to the boolean finished. Now it works! Thanks alot ill post the full code for comprehension in a sec.!

Answer (score 0):

I introduced a new Boolean called finished, which was set to false by default and to true during collision.

```
      if (block[i].x < 130) {
        if(block[i].y > cY && block[i].y < (cY+cW) && !finished){
            //println(collide_count + " with");
            collide_count = 80;
            finished = true;
           currentCount = frameCount/20;

          }
```

In the collison i set currentCount= Framecount and let the score be printed when finished == true.

```
  public void draw () {

    Scorevar = frameCount/20;
    textFont(font);
    fill (0);
    //textAlign(CENTER);
    textMode(MODEL);
    if ( finished == true) {
      text("Score = "+ currentCount, x, y);
    }
   else {
      text("Score = "+ Scorevar, x, y);
    }
  }
```

Thanks alot again!